# Fragment not attached to a context - Delayed UI changes

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-context, illegalstateexception, coroutinescope

I am working with Fragments, and in a specific Fragment, I need to change the UI after a delay. I have found some code online which allows me to do so (using a Timer + CoroutineScope to touch the views).

```
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                MainScope().launch {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    }
                    changeUI(requireContext())
                }
            }
        }, 800)
```

It does the job, but I am sure it is not best practice (I am relatively new to programming, so please do not be too harsh on it). The problem is that I require a context to be passed to the method which changes the UI, and I am getting an occasional `IllegalStageException` because the Fragment is not attached to a context.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Is there a better way to deal with delayed changes in the UI?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is because `Fragment`s follow the Android `lifecycle`, there are states in the  `lifecycle` where it can't manipulate its view. This typically happens when the `Fragment` is not actually viewable on the screen.

```
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                MainScope().launch {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    }
                    if(isAdded()){
                          changeUI(requireContext())                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 800)
```

You can check if the `Fragment` is in a valid state to manipulate its view by calling `isAdded()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What would be such states? Like onPause, onStop? And could you please let me know if the solution I used (timer + MainScope) is good practice or if I should use alternative code? Thanks! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes those are states or stages just do a quick google on `Android Lifecycle`. Ideally you would want a `Lifecyle` aware approach. Here is one that uses the `CountDownTimer `
 https://mahendranv.github.io/posts/timer/  You will have to adapt it to your current use case as `Timer` and `CountDownTimer ` are different.  It will at least give you a hint on how to make something `Lifecycle` aware. You could also stick the timer in a `ViewModel` and have it post changes via `LiveData`, which the `observers` themselves are `Lifecycle` aware.